# Validation VBA multiple conditions

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I am trying to write a VBA macro that:

1) Takes the selected active cell at the moment.

2) Does a data validation if the the value is a number less or equal to another cell (B2 for instance that contains a number too).

3) OR has the value in the active cell is equal to the string "NA" inserted by the user.

This is the code I came up with so far:

```
Sub Macro()
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlLessEqual, Formula1:="=OR(" & ActiveCell.Value & "=""NA"",AND(ISNUMBER(" & ActiveCell.Value & ")," & ActiveCell.Value & "<=B2))"
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

But it keeps giving me a:

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object defined error.

Do you have any solution for this issue?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Try, please changing of `ActiveCell.value` with `ActiveCell.Address`... In `Formula1:="=OR(" & ActiveCell.Value & "=""NA"",AND(ISNUMBER(" & ActiveCell.Value & ")," & ActiveCell.Value & "<=B2))"` In three places. I do not comment the logic of your conditions, but in this way you will not receive the error, anymore...

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You need to reference the address of the cell rather than its value.

```
Sub Macro()

With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateCustom, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=OR(" & ActiveCell.Address & "=""NA"",AND(ISNUMBER(" & ActiveCell.Address & ")," & ActiveCell.Address & "<=B2))"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With

End Sub
```